# What is the difference between segmented regression analysis and cate-nelson analysis?

Tags: regression, linear

I observed a possible inflection point for my dataset and was introduced to segmented regression analysis and cate-nelson analysis. The segmented regression analysis seems to fit better for my dataset. I would like to know what is the theoretical difference between these two types of analysis? How do I decide or justify which analytical tool to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cate-Nelson analysis](https://www.joe.org/joe/2013october/tt1.php) and segmented regression are really quite different, though they are sometimes used in similar situations.  They are both used in cases of bivariate data where the variables have a relationship that wouldn't be described well with a simple linear regression or nonlinear regression.

They are also often used to determine a "critical value".  In segmented regresion, this is the x value where the two segments meet.  In Cate-Nelson, this is the x value which separates the two groups of values.  I find it useful if software can report a confidence interval about this critical value.

Segmented regression is useful when the data follow the shape of two linear --- or curvilinear --- segments.

[In the following example](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/C_04.html#_Toc459550396) of a linear-plateau model, Life expectancy increases linearly, up to a point (about 2500 $/yr).  Above this x value, the data are fit with a linear segment with 0 slope.

http://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image042.png

Note that this data could also be fit with a quadratic-plateau model, which has a more more natural transition between the two segments (critical x about 3500 $/yr).

http://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image041.png

Cate-Nelson analysis is very different.  It is used to simply divide the bivariate data so that most of the data fall into a group with a high x and high y value or a low x and low y value.

[In the following example](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/h_02.html), operations to the left of the vertical line (smaller than about 4 hectares) tend to have low rates of adoption, while those to the right of the vertical line tend to have high rates of adoption. 87% of observations fall within quadrants II and IV of the plot.

http://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/images/h_02_03.png

Cate-Nelson analysis is useful in cases where the data could be seen to fall into quadrants like this, but don't follow a pattern such that it would be easy to fit a linear or nonlinear model to them.  For example, in the preceding plot, for x values below about 5, the y values don't really increase as x increases.  Traditionally, Cate-Nelson was also very useful because it didn't require much computing power:  The critical x and y values could be estimated manually and the points falling into quadrants could be counted.  It's also possible to set the y critical value.  For example, if the y-axis is crop yield, it could be set to 90% of the maximum to find the x value that separates > 90% yield from < 90% yield.

Comment: Hi Sal, thanks for the explanation. So, if my data can be simply divided into two population, can i say that segmented linear regression is a better tool to analyse them and if my data can't be simply divided into two populations, eg. falls into 3 or 4 quadrants, then i should consider Cate-Nelson analysis?

Comment: I also consider about statistical significant and practical significant for my data. Looking at this data for example: https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/images/h_02_04.png, if the y ranging from ~50 to 80, of which their difference has no practical significant, and those points in quadrant II and IV are possibly measurement error, then what we possibly seeing is a negative linear, proceeded with a flat response. In this case, would segmented linear regression analysis be used?

Comment: @Catalyst, I'm not sure what you mean by "if my data can be simply divided into two population"... One consideration:  segmented regression is usually done by a least-squares method, so you probably want normal and homoscedastic errors.  The fitting can also be thrown off by outliers.  There may be more robust methods of fitting the models.

Comment: @Catalyst , The Cate and Nelson (1971) paper also uses a least-squares method, so you could probably come up with some situations where outliers would throw the algorithm for a curve, but 1) you don't need to use this algorithm, and 2) the final model just counts where points fall, so it doesn't rely on any distributional assumptions about the data.

Comment: "if my data can be simply divided into two populations"...what i mean here is if my data looks like http://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image042.png. From this data, we can divide them into two populations or two groups, one linear and one flat response. And i think you have made an important point here about normal and homoscedastic errors when performing this analysis.

Comment: Could you explain more when you said, "the final model just counts where points fall, so it doesn't rely on any distributional assumptions about the data"?

Comment: Yes, if your data look like a linear model, then a linear model is probably a good choice.  If your data look like a linear plateau model, then a linear plateau model is probably a good choice.  But note that usually we use the fitting algorithm to find the point where the two segments meet; we don't divide the data beforehand.

Comment: In essence Cate-Nelson is 1) plot the bivariate data. 2) draw a vertical line and a horizontal line.  3) count how many points fall in which quadrants.  There are different ways to do step 2.   I grew up using the sum-of-squares approach in Cate and Nelson (1971), but if I rewrote the function today, it would just try every combination of horizontal and vertical line.  That would also make it easier to fix the value of one of the lines.

Comment: The result is just counting how many points fell into, say, quadrants II and IV.  You say, "85% of the points fell into Q II and IV.  That's pretty good."  The upshot here is that you don't have to worry about outliers, or if the residuals are normally distributed or anything.  (With the caveats above about the sum-of-squares method).

Comment: Ok, i think i have better understanding now. Thanks for your time. I've also found that you wrote this http://rcompanion.org/handbook/index.html and they are very useful. Good work!